# Django form - user url attr to fill automatically the form - RelatedObjectDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I'm still stuck with my issue. So I've found a new way to do it. Better I think Your help will be really appreciate.

```
path('new/<seller>/', CreateChannelSellerView.as_view(),name="channel_to"),
```

**Assume I got .../new/fredo/** -> fredo is the username of the seller. I want to catch it. But I got an issue:

Exception Type: **RelatedObjectDoesNotExist**
Exception Value:
Channel has no seller.

Trace:

- form.instance.seller.add(existed_seller)
- "%s has no %s." % (self.field.model.**name**, self.field.name)

views.py

```
class CreateChannelSellerView(CreateView):
    model = Channel
    form_class = CreateSellerChannelForm
    template_name = 'channel_seller_new.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.consumer = self.request.user
        seller_field = self.kwargs['seller']
        current_seller = User.objects.filter(username=seller_field)
        if current_seller.count()<1:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Username does not exist')
        else:
            existed_seller = User.objects.get(username=seller_field)
            form.instance.seller.add(existed_seller)
            
        form.save()    
        return super(CreateChannelSellerView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('channel:channel_home')
```

models.py

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_seller")
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = unique_slugify(self, slugify(self.name))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CreateSellerChannelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Channel
        widgets = {
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'','style':'','placeholder':'First group'}),
            
        }
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `.add()` here, it's used for the "other side" of Foreign Key relation which is `seller.channel_set`. If you want to assign a seller, simply do `form.instance.seller = existed_seller`

Comment: Ah you saved my life and a lot of time that works well :) thanks a lot